# OCaml how to fix module name collisions

Tags: namespaces, ocaml

When making a toplevel, module names are not allowed to conflict with internal compiler libs.

What are some strategies for fixing this sorts of module name collisions?

Ideally, is it possible to pass some argument to `ocamlc` to instruct it to "mangle" the names of all the modules to use a custom prefix like `MyProject_`? (from the perspective of the OCaml ABI, not literally changing source files)

Full example below:

`Sqrt.ml` contains

```
let sqrt x = x ** 0.5
```

`Sqrt.mli` contains

```
val sqrt : float -> float
```

`mktop` contains

```
#!/bin/bash

ocamlc -c Sqrt.mli -o Sqrt.cmi 
ocamlc -c Sqrt.ml  -o Sqrt.cmo

ocamlmktop -o sqrt_toplevel Sqrt.cmo
```

And I can produce a toplevel containing the function I want.

```
% ./sqrt_toplevel
        OCaml version 4.04.0

# Sqrt.sqrt 4.5;;
- : float = 2.12132034355964239
```

If I rename the `Sqrt` module to `Parse` by changing the file names, the name conflicts with an internal library and the toplevel fails to link.

`mktop` is now

```
#!/bin/bash

ocamlc -c Parse.mli -o Parse.cmi 
ocamlc -c Parse.ml  -o Parse.cmo

ocamlmktop -o parse_toplevel Parse.cmo
```

with the other files simply renamed to `Parse.ml` and `Parse.mli`.

If I do this, I get a naming conflict with a compiler lib.

```
% ./mktop |& sed -e s:"$HOME":~:
File "Parse.cmo", line 1:
Warning 31: files Parse.cmo and ~/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlcommon.cma(Parse) both define a module named Parse
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Some fatal warnings were triggered (1 occurrences)
Exit 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a documented way to avoid this problem other than by using names that don't conflict with internal modules.

Here are Unix commands to list all the forbidden names, which is at least something:

```
$ cd ~/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
$ ocamlobjinfo ocamlbytecomp.cma ocamlcommon.cma ocamltoplevel.cma |
    awk '/^Unit name:/ { print $3}' | sort
```

For me (using OCaml 4.03.0 right now) there are 96 forbidden names. I wrote a script to verify that all 96 are really forbidden.

As a side comment, the toplevel is in fact generated in spite of the reported error. And, in a quick test, it seems to work. The function `Parse.sqrt` (for example) exists and computes the right answers. But possibly there are problems that I just didn't happen to encounter.

Answer (score 4):

Dune/jbuilder by default will wrap your modules into a containing module named after your library. While this doesn't give you proper namespaces, you only have to ensure that your library names are unique.

A [sample project](https://github.com/mjambon/dune-starter) can have the following structure:

```
proj
├── Makefile
├── proj.opam
├── README.md
├── sub1
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── a.ml
│   │   ├── a.mli
│   │   ├── b.ml
│   │   └── jbuild
│   └── test
│       ├── a.ml
│       ├── b.ml
│       └── jbuild
├── sub2
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── bar_main.ml
│   │   ├── foo_main.ml
│   │   └── jbuild
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── a.ml
│   │   └── jbuild
│   └── test
│       ├── a.ml
│       └── jbuild
└── test
    ├── jbuild
    └── run_tests.ml
```

Note how we have multiple `a.ml` and `b.ml` files.

The `jbuild` file in `sub1/lib` is:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

; name = name of the supermodule that will wrap all source files as submodules
; public_name = name of the library for ocamlfind and opam
(library
 ((name proj_sub1)
  (public_name proj.sub1)
  (libraries (unix))
  (synopsis "This is a short description of the sub1 library.")))
```

This will result in modules `Proj_sub1.A` and `Proj_sub1.B` corresponding to `sub1/lib/a.ml` and `sub2/lib/b.ml` respectively. Similarly, we also build `Test_sub1.A`, `Test_sub1.B`, `Proj_sub2.A`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using ocamlbuild, one standard way of achievieng this is to encapsulate your modules into an mlpack as described in : http://l-lang.blogspot.fr/2012/12/using-ocaml-packages-with-ocamlbuild.html

*File: repo/A.ml*

```
let a = 3;;
```

*File: repo/b.ml*

```
let b = A.a;;
```

*File: repo.mlpack*

```
repo/A
repo/B
```

*File: main.ml*

```
Repo.B.b
```

This tackles the name collision issue but forces you to access your module through a "super-module"